# Force Close of my program

Tags: android

I develop an application that record video and then save it in custom folder
the code is ok and no syntax error...
however when I run the apps in my phone, after I finish my recording then came to force close processes, why it happen?
here is my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private Uri fileUri;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //create new Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);  // create a file to save the video
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // set the video image quality to high*/

        // start the Video Capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);


    }




    @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to :\n" +
                         fileUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the video capture
            } else {
                // Video capture failed, advise user
            }
        }
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    public void inputFileName(){

    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

         File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

     // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.cameratesting"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My logcat(com.example.cameratesting)

```
11-25 21:14:19.799: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity bnds=[62,153][118,218] } from pid 234
11-25 21:14:35.719: I/ActivityManager(160): Start proc com.example.cameratesting for activity com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity: pid=14732 uid=10052 gids={1006, 1015}
11-25 21:14:38.409: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity: +1m10s22ms (total +2s710ms)
11-25 21:14:52.359: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0, channel '408c2d78 com.example.cameratesting/com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity (server)'
11-25 21:14:52.540: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering key to current input target: action: 1, channel '408c2d78 com.example.cameratesting/com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity (server)'
11-25 21:21:14.450: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity bnds=[62,153][118,218] } from pid 234
11-25 21:21:14.500: W/ActivityManager(160): Trying to launch com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity
11-25 21:21:35.159: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity: +20s664ms
11-25 21:21:59.180: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity bnds=[62,153][118,218] } from pid 234
11-25 21:22:07.600: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0, channel '40916378 com.example.cameratesting/com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity (server)'
11-25 21:22:07.779: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering key to current input target: action: 1, channel '40916378 com.example.cameratesting/com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity (server)'
11-25 21:22:08.879: E/ATK(13151): com.example.cameratesting
11-25 21:22:12.579: I/PackageManager(160): Removing non-system package:com.example.cameratesting
11-25 21:22:12.579: I/ActivityManager(160): Force stopping package com.example.cameratesting uid=10052
11-25 21:22:12.759: D/PackageManager(160): Scanning package com.example.cameratesting
11-25 21:22:12.769: I/PackageManager(160): Package com.example.cameratesting codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.cameratesting-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.cameratesting-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
11-25 21:22:12.769: I/PackageManager(160): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.example.cameratesting-2.apk
11-25 21:22:13.709: D/PackageManager(160):   Activities: com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity
11-25 21:22:13.709: I/ActivityManager(160): Force stopping package com.example.cameratesting uid=10052
11-25 21:22:13.709: W/PackageManager(160): Code path for pkg : com.example.cameratesting changing from /data/app/com.example.cameratesting-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.cameratesting-2.apk
11-25 21:22:13.709: W/PackageManager(160): Resource path for pkg : com.example.cameratesting changing from /data/app/com.example.cameratesting-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.cameratesting-2.apk
11-25 21:22:13.959: D/PackageManager(160): New package installed in /data/app/com.example.cameratesting-2.apk
11-25 21:22:13.959: W/PackageManager(160): Unknown permission android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA in package com.example.cameratesting
11-25 21:22:13.959: W/PackageManager(160): Unknown permission android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA in package com.example.cameratesting
11-25 21:22:13.959: W/PackageManager(160): Unknown permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in package com.example.cameratesting
11-25 21:22:14.209: I/ActivityManager(160): Force stopping package com.example.cameratesting uid=10052
11-25 21:22:15.619: I/UinboxLogger(15063): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >>   intent.getData() : com.example.cameratesting
11-25 21:22:15.639: V/PackageIntentReceiver(13466): onReceive() intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.cameratesting flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sec.android.app.controlpanel/.PackageIntentReceiver (has extras) } pkg:com.example.cameratesting action:android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
11-25 21:22:17.499: I/ActivityManager(160): Force stopping package com.example.cameratesting uid=10052
11-25 21:22:17.499: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity } from pid 15065
11-25 21:22:17.549: I/ActivityManager(160): Start proc com.example.cameratesting for activity com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity: pid=15085 uid=10052 gids={1006, 1015}
11-25 21:22:17.789: W/ActivityThread(15085): Application com.example.cameratesting is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-25 21:22:22.879: V/PackageIntentReceiver(13466): onReceive() intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.cameratesting flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sec.android.app.controlpanel/.PackageIntentReceiver (has extras) } pkg:com.example.cameratesting action:android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
11-25 21:22:30.319: I/ActivityManager(160): No longer want com.example.cameratesting (pid 15085): hidden #16
11-25 21:22:50.849: I/ActivityManager(160): Start proc com.example.cameratesting for activity com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity: pid=15285 uid=10052 gids={1006, 1015}
11-25 21:22:53.029: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity: +35s490ms (total +2s192ms)
11-25 21:22:53.979: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0, channel '408b9c80 com.example.cameratesting/com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity (server)'
11-25 21:22:54.119: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering key to current input target: action: 1, channel '408b9c80 com.example.cameratesting/com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity (server)'
11-25 21:22:55.299: E/ATK(13151): com.example.cameratesting
11-25 21:25:42.270: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity bnds=[62,153][118,218] } from pid 234
11-25 21:25:42.349: I/ActivityManager(160): Start proc com.example.cameratesting for activity com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity: pid=15542 uid=10052 gids={1006, 1015}
11-25 21:26:00.489: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed com.example.cameratesting/.MainActivity: +18s151ms
11-25 21:26:03.149: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0, channel '407d0678 com.example.cameratesting/com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity (server)'
11-25 21:26:03.209: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering key to current input target: action: 1, channel '407d0678 com.example.cameratesting/com.example.cameratesting.MainActivity (server)'
```

logcat(camcorder)

```
11-25 21:14:19.829: I/ActivityManager(160): Start proc com.sec.android.app.camera for activity com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder: pid=14663 uid=10040 gids={1006, 1015}
11-25 21:14:20.669: E/Camcorder(14663): Initialize Camcorder Sound
11-25 21:14:20.959: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder: +1s149ms
11-25 21:14:21.899: I/QualcommCameraHardware(95): <=PCAM=>NOW CAMCORDER MODE~~~~~~ 
11-25 21:14:25.019: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40974370 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:14:25.129: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40974370 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:14:25.479: E/VENC_ENC(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venci_process_command_init::3105 initializing camcorder application...
11-25 21:14:25.499: E/VENC_ENC(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venci_init_encoder::2391 set camcorder rate control config...
11-25 21:14:25.529: E/VENC_DRV(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venc_drv_start::614 camcorder pass for DSP
11-25 21:14:28.609: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40974370 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:14:28.639: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40974370 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:14:29.099: E/AndroidRuntime(14663):    at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.renameTempFile(CamcorderEngine.java:1151)
11-25 21:14:29.099: E/AndroidRuntime(14663):    at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.doStopVideoRecordingSync(CamcorderEngine.java:780)
11-25 21:14:29.119: W/ActivityManager(160):   Force finishing activity com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder
11-25 21:14:29.619: W/ActivityManager(160): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40545450 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder}
11-25 21:14:36.399: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder (has extras) } from pid 14732
11-25 21:14:36.469: W/ActivityManager(160): Trying to launch com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder
11-25 21:14:37.989: I/WindowManager(160): WIN DEATH: Window{40974370 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder paused=false}
11-25 21:14:45.769: W/ActivityManager(160): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40545450 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder}
11-25 21:21:14.600: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder (has extras) } from pid 14732
11-25 21:21:14.620: I/ActivityManager(160): Start proc com.sec.android.app.camera for activity com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder: pid=14960 uid=10040 gids={1006, 1015}
11-25 21:21:15.750: E/Camcorder(14960): Initialize Camcorder Sound
11-25 21:21:15.960: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder: +1s340ms (total +1s458ms)
11-25 21:21:16.920: I/QualcommCameraHardware(95): <=PCAM=>NOW CAMCORDER MODE~~~~~~ 
11-25 21:21:22.989: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40c36608 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:21:23.079: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40c36608 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:21:23.349: E/VENC_ENC(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venci_process_command_init::3105 initializing camcorder application...
11-25 21:21:23.349: E/VENC_ENC(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venci_init_encoder::2391 set camcorder rate control config...
11-25 21:21:23.369: E/VENC_DRV(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venc_drv_start::614 camcorder pass for DSP
11-25 21:21:27.329: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40c36608 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:21:27.439: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40c36608 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(14960):    at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.renameTempFile(CamcorderEngine.java:1151)
11-25 21:21:27.709: E/AndroidRuntime(14960):    at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.doStopVideoRecordingSync(CamcorderEngine.java:780)
11-25 21:21:27.739: W/ActivityManager(160):   Force finishing activity com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder
11-25 21:21:28.249: W/ActivityManager(160): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40d17e40 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder}
11-25 21:21:36.739: I/WindowManager(160): WIN DEATH: Window{40c36608 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder paused=false}
11-25 21:21:45.170: W/ActivityManager(160): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40d17e40 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder}
11-25 21:22:20.139: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder (has extras) } from pid 15085
11-25 21:22:20.189: I/ActivityManager(160): Start proc com.sec.android.app.camera for activity com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder: pid=15105 uid=10040 gids={1006, 1015}
11-25 21:22:22.099: E/Camcorder(15105): Initialize Camcorder Sound
11-25 21:22:22.369: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder: +2s184ms (total +4s829ms)
11-25 21:22:23.489: I/QualcommCameraHardware(95): <=PCAM=>NOW CAMCORDER MODE~~~~~~ 
11-25 21:22:34.229: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '409d4988 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:22:34.329: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '409d4988 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:22:34.639: E/VENC_ENC(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venci_process_command_init::3105 initializing camcorder application...
11-25 21:22:34.679: E/VENC_ENC(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venci_init_encoder::2391 set camcorder rate control config...
11-25 21:22:34.699: E/VENC_DRV(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venc_drv_start::614 camcorder pass for DSP
11-25 21:22:44.099: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '409d4988 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:22:44.159: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '409d4988 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:22:44.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15105):    at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.renameTempFile(CamcorderEngine.java:1151)
11-25 21:22:44.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15105):    at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.doStopVideoRecordingSync(CamcorderEngine.java:780)
11-25 21:22:44.439: W/ActivityManager(160):   Force finishing activity com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder
11-25 21:22:44.949: W/ActivityManager(160): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4096e880 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder}
11-25 21:22:51.329: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder (has extras) } from pid 15285
11-25 21:22:51.389: W/ActivityManager(160): Trying to launch com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder
11-25 21:22:52.669: I/WindowManager(160): WIN DEATH: Window{409d4988 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder paused=false}
11-25 21:23:00.939: W/ActivityManager(160): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4096e880 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder}
11-25 21:25:42.509: I/ActivityManager(160): Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder (has extras) } from pid 15542
11-25 21:25:42.529: I/ActivityManager(160): Start proc com.sec.android.app.camera for activity com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder: pid=15550 uid=10040 gids={1006, 1015}
11-25 21:25:43.379: E/Camcorder(15550): Initialize Camcorder Sound
11-25 21:25:43.599: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder: +1s81ms (total +1s257ms)
11-25 21:25:44.609: I/QualcommCameraHardware(95): <=PCAM=>NOW CAMCORDER MODE~~~~~~ 
11-25 21:25:47.169: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40a5e5a8 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:25:47.299: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40a5e5a8 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:25:47.559: E/VENC_ENC(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venci_process_command_init::3105 initializing camcorder application...
11-25 21:25:47.599: E/VENC_ENC(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venci_init_encoder::2391 set camcorder rate control config...
11-25 21:25:47.609: E/VENC_DRV(95): VENC_MSG_HIGH venc_drv_start::614 camcorder pass for DSP
11-25 21:25:52.289: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40a5e5a8 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:25:52.409: I/InputDispatcher(160): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40a5e5a8 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder (server)'
11-25 21:25:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.renameTempFile(CamcorderEngine.java:1151)
11-25 21:25:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.doStopVideoRecordingSync(CamcorderEngine.java:780)
11-25 21:25:52.699: W/ActivityManager(160):   Force finishing activity com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder
11-25 21:25:53.209: W/ActivityManager(160): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40a6f418 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder}
11-25 21:26:01.899: I/WindowManager(160): WIN DEATH: Window{40a5e5a8 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder paused=false}
11-25 21:26:10.360: W/ActivityManager(160): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40a6f418 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camcorder}
```

Comment: make sure you have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> `permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: sir, imran khan, i already added this permission...

Comment: when i remove "intent.getExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri);"
it work and no any force close process...

Comment: How can we guess if you don't tell us what the error is? Please post your logcat stack trace.

Comment: Sir Simon, please wait a second, I upload now, sorry

Comment: @user1851081 : where is logcat?

Comment: sir, i dunno how to upload log cat, here i upload my manifest
sorry...
@Simon

Comment: Sir, I already uploaded my logcat...
tqvm

Comment: @imran khan : i uploaded logcat

Comment: @user1851081 : if you comment all code within `onActivityResult` then what is behavior of Application?

Comment: @imran khan : sir imran, what you mean?

Comment: @imrankhan : sir imran, my video saved correctly in custom folder and the name also correct, but I still don't understand why it will be force process

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your Manifest file nor stacktrace (LogCat output) but most likely your application crashes due to not holding right permission to access SD card. Add this to your `<manifest>` block in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I'd also add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

as required by API16

Comment: Sir, i already add them in manifest, and my logcat din function, it din show anything as well

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the method "File getOutputMediaFile(int type)(){}" is returning null.

Comment: No sir, the video saved correctly in the custom folder, but don't know why it will be force close process...